# Fitting logarithmic regression on time series data containing zero in it ? (using R tool )

Tags: r, regression, logarithm

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53624395/11.csv

This is time series data and I have to perform logarithmic regression of form `y=a+b(log(x1))+c(log(x2))`  and find a,b,c and then check is there any such type of relation exists or not.
I have to do this using R tool.I have posted this question on http://stats.stackexchange.com but it was closed by saying that it should be posted on StackOverflow since it is totally related to R programming.Please help.

Data:

```
structure(list(x = c(433.66, 433, 230, 0, 251, 0, 424, 0, 439, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 85.15, 0, 0, 748, 0, 732, 0, 523.76, 0, 780, 0, 778, 
0, 635.64, 0, 600, 0), y = c(9.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
z = c(43504.95, 49380, 50601, 0, 36064, 0, 47081, 0, 43775, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 85.15, 0, 0, 68502, 0, 66397, 0, 47565.35, 0, 
65695, 0, 69111, 0, 53213.86, 0, 118891, 0), x1 = c(1382.18, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1306, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1473.27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
2, 3, 2.1, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), x4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
43L, 11L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z", "x1", "x2", "x3", 
"x4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: Assuming this is called 'logdat' you should take a look at `with(logdat, table(x1,x2,y))`. To call this a "time series" seems puzzling.

Comment: Before this becomes a programming question (how to implement in R), you have to answer a modeling question: how to avoid those `log(0)`. So again, this is not a question for SO but for stackexchange. Maybe it would help the peeps on stackexchange realize it if you stripped off any implementation details from your question. (And BTW I bet it must have been answered many times before...) Closing as off topic.

Answer (score 2):

What are asking to do is impossible.  But you can get close.

Try this: `y = a + b(log(x1 + 1)) + c(log(x2 + 1))`

Naming your data frame `x`

```
x <- read.csv('11.csv')

lm(y ~ 1 + log(x1+1) + log(x2+1), data=x)

## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ 1 + log(x1 + 1) + log(x2 + 1), data = x)
##
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)  log(x1 + 1)  log(x2 + 1)  
##  -1.202e-04    1.312e+00    1.648e-05
```

Comment: I completely agree with you.
Thanks For your Reply.
But I have a doubt rather than adding one ,is there any way to add some other constant to reduce affect on data.

If yes,what should be the procedure to calculate that constant.
Kindly suggest.:)

Comment: @Manish Add a constant to what?  If it is to the `x` values, `1` is the ideal value.  And @flodel is correct above, this is not a programming problem.